# Getting IP Address and Location of my own server instead of visiting User's

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, geolocation

I have a MEAN Stack application deployed on a server and am using Nginx as proxy server to handle the request and redirect to application's particular port.

For example: User accesses the URL `http://www.abcxyz.com/` and Nginx hits the actual application URL `http://www.abcxyz.com:1234/`, as my application is running on port 1234.

Now, for analytics purpose I wrote a short script in node.js which fetches IP and location of the users visiting my website. I can see the externally searched queries but I am getting the IP address and location of my own server. Why is that?

Is that because of Nginx? How can I resolve this and fetch the user's actual location?

> Update: I have added an Answer, which works for me. Cheers ;-)

Comment: I do not see why this has the google-analytics tag. Can you explain why this  is there (or remove it)?

Comment: sorry, i updated the question and forgot to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using express:

> Setting a non-false trust proxy value results in three important
>   changes:
>
> The value of req.hostname is derived from the value set in the
>   X-Forwarded-Host header, which can be set by the client or by the
>   proxy.
>
> X-Forwarded-Proto can be set by the reverse proxy to tell the app
>   whether it is https or http or even an invalid name. This value is
>   reflected by req.protocol.
>
> The req.ip and req.ips values are populated with the list of addresses
>   from X-Forwarded-For.

http://expressjs.com/es/guide/behind-proxies.html

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(req.ip, req.ips);
    //Do whatever you want or call next()       
});
```

If you're not using express, you can get the IP from the header: `x-forwarded-for`

```
let ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

If you're not getting the correct IP, you need to have the correct settings in Nginx:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;`

or to append the remote users IP to any existing X-Forwarded-For value:

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`

Comment: Please explain the part using with express, how can I access those variables in my API? and `var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;` returns `::1`.

Comment: As you can see in my example, you can access req.ip in any middleware, maybe if you provide some code, I can be more specific.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick response... I have placed `app.enable('trust proxy');` in my server.ts file right after my following code `import { serverApi, createTodoApi } from './backend/api'; app.get('/data.json', serverApi); app.use('/api', createTodoApi());` and accessing the variables `req.ip` in my backend/api.ts file. Where its returning `::ffff:127.0.0.1`, which is not a valid ip address to fetch the location out of it.

Comment: @DynamicRemo check my updated answer, containing Nginx setup.

Comment: I did the same but still no success. Its returning the same. Here's my Nginx Conf `location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }`
Waiting for your response. Thanks

Comment: Now i have some new results. When ever i go for `http:www.abcxyz.com` it gives the ip `::ffff:127.0.0.1` but as soon as i attach my port number to website url `http:www.abcxyz.com:1234` it gives actual public ip of the client. I believe there's some config issue in my Nginx as URL without port number renders via Nginx. Waiting for your response. Thanks

Comment: The code I provided is working correctly in my servers using AWS Load balancer or Nginx. Can you please update your question showing some express code. Thanks.

Comment: You may try: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` instead of `$remote_addr`

Comment: Thank you to @Marcos Casagrande for your answer. Although i had to work around for additional 3hours after your answer but your leads help me resolve the issue and thats the reason why I am accepting your answer. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to say thank you to `@Marcos Casagrande` for his answer.
>   Although i had to work around for additional 3hours after his answer but will
>   accept his lead as an answer to my question.

Here's the Nginx Conf which works for me, placed at the path `/etc/nginx/conf.d/abcxyz.com.conf`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name abcxyz.com;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:1234/";
    }
}
```

No other Nginx Conf required, as of my previous implementation i was having another conf file at the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` directory which was conflicting as a Duplicate Server Name.
Lastly, i would like to add that use Nginx Testing command before resetting the changes. Which was a huge help.  **Command: `nginx -t`**.

And in Node.js, this is the most appropriate way to access Client's IP Address.

```
var getClientAddress = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',')[0] 
                       || req.connection.remoteAddress;
console.log(getClientAddress);
```

Cheers ;-)